# get the first and last dates of the previous 3 months in Go

Tags: go, time

How to get the first and last dates of the last 3 months in Go?
example:

```
{"start": "2020-05-01", "end": "2020-07-31"}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Go has a [time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package with many utilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use golang [`time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package.

```
currentTime := time.Now()

last3Month := currentTime.AddDate(0,-3,0)

goneDaysOfMonth := last3Month.Day()

firstDay := last3Month.AddDate(0,0,-goneDaysOfMonth+1)
lastDay  := last3Month.AddDate(0,3,-goneDaysOfMonth)

timeLayout := "2006-01-02"

fmt.Println(firstDay.Format(timeLayout))
fmt.Println(lastDay.Format(timeLayout))
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8590omPWHZt)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @ttrasn works fine (and you should definitely use the time package!) however I felt it was worthwhile posting an alternative approach ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bWOkgUWmJmj)):

```
year, month, _ := currentTime.Date()
startTime := time.Date(year, month-3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, currentTime.Location())
endTime := startTime.AddDate(0, 3, 0).Add(-time.Nanosecond)

const layout = "2006-01-02"
fmt.Println(startTime.Format(layout), endTime.Format(layout))
```

Using `Time.Date` makes it simple to set `startTime` to the start of the desired month (the time component is set to midnight). Note that `time.Date` will handle negative months correctly.

To work out the end time we add three months and then subtract a nanosecond (bringing the time back to the end of the previous month).

Running this today (in UTC) the full values calculated are:

```
startTime: 2020-05-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
endTime:   2020-07-31 23:59:59.999999999 +0000 UTC
```

Using the solution from @ttrasn these would be:

```
firstDay: 2020-05-01 08:56:46.000001 +0000 UTC
lastDay:  2020-07-31 08:56:46.000001 +0000 UTC
```

(the time component will depend upon the time part of `currentTime`).

So the benefit of my solution is that the time range calculated covers the entire month. This is not directly relevant to your requirement (because the time component is not used) but can be important (for example when making database queries).